# each() or map() to get all data attributes from DOM element?

Tags: jquery

Which is the best way (performance, etc) between each or map to get all data attributes from DOM elements?

```
<table id="tbl">
  <tr> 
    <th data-id="one" data-name="foo">
    <th data-id="two" data-name="bar" data-sort="no">
    ...
```

`map()`:

```
var params = $("#tbl").find("th").map(function() {
  return $(this).data();
}).get();
```

Or `each()`:

```
var params = [];
$("#tbl").find("th").each(function() {
  params.push($(this).data());
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Either works fine, but `map()` is more succinct. I doubt there's any real difference between them in term of performance - although if you're that concerned with how fast this runs you probably shouldn't be using jQuery at all

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much